# Problem logging into Backend of Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have the following error what should I do?

> Fatal error: Uncaught Zend_Cache_Exception: cache_dir
>   "/home/tradesignletters/public_html/var/page_cache" is not writable in
>   /home/tradesignletters/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php:209
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/tradesignletters/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php(180):
>   Zend_Cache::throwException('cache_dir "/hom...') #1
>   /home/tradesignletters/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php(87):
>   Zend_Cache_Backend_File->setCacheDir('/home/tradesign...') #2
>   /home/tradesignletters/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(153):
>   Cm_Cache_Backend_File->__construct(Array) #3
>   /home/tradesignletters/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(94):
>   Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, true, true) #4
>   /home/tradesignletters/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php(154):
>   Zend_Cache::factory('Magento\Framewo...', 'Cm_Cache_Backen...',
>   Array, Array, true, true, tru in
>   /home/tradesignletters/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php
>   on line 209

Answer (score 0):

Run this command below

> php bin/magento cache:flush
>
> php bin/magento cache:clean
>
> chmod -R 777 var/ pub/

Answer (score 0):

This is permission issue. Just set below permission to folders

> find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;                        // 644
>   permission for files
>
> find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;                        // 755
>   permission for directory
>
> find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;                // 777
>   permission for var folder
>
> find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
>
> find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
>
> chmod 777 ./app/etc
>
> chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml

Answer (score -2):

If it is Magento 2.2 please run this command below

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
```